# Transition an SVG Filter

Tags: html, css, svg, material-design, svg-filters

I'm trying to create a material design like shadow on an SVG circle. I want this shadow to grow with a nice transition when you click on the circle, but at the moment I'm struggling to even figure out if it's possible to animate this transition, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

I've added a small example of what I've got so far, a circle with a dropshadow which changes on mouseover. I spent quite a while trying to do the dropshadow in CSS but came to the conclusion that I don't think it's possible right now.

Now that I've got the shadows though, I can't find a way to animate them. I've found some example using animation tags for single properties (e.g. colour of the circle) and found examples using keyframes for CSS transitions, but here I want to modify the actual filter itself. Is this possible and can someone illustrate how you might achieve this - ideally I'm trying to achieve IE10/FF/Chrome compatibility so I'd be interested to know if there are any complications with the solution?

```css
circle {
    fill: #8BC34A;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    filter: url(#f1);
    transition: 2s ease;
}

circle:hover {
    filter: url(#f2);
    transition: 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" viewPort="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="10" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="f2" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="30" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle r="100" cx="150" cy="150" />
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

After trying a few things, I've put some examples together, although none of them quite do what I want. I need to be able to toggle the transitions on a single/several element (rather than every circle in the SVG), for which I may have several hundred. I also ultimately want to be changing both the size of the circle (lifting as per material design) and then increasing the side of the shadow underneath.

```js
/*************************/
/* JavaScript Animations */
/*************************/
(function() { 
    var svg = d3.select("#svg_javaScriptAnimation");
    setInterval(function() {
        
        // Animate
        svg.selectAll(".circle")
           .transition()
           .duration(1950)
           .attr("r", 130);
        
        svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow")
           .transition()
           .duration(1950)
           .attr("r", 130);
        
         svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow_expanding")
           .transition()
           .duration(1950)
           .attr("r", 140);
        
        svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow_large")
           .transition()
           .duration(1950)
           .attr("r", 110);
        
        // Reset
         svg.selectAll(".circle")
           .transition()
           .delay(1960)
           .duration(1)
           .attr("r", 110);
        
         svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow")
           .transition()
           .delay(1960)
           .duration(1)
           .attr("r", 110);
        
         svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow_expanding")
           .transition()
           .delay(1960)
           .duration(1)
           .attr("r", 110);
        
        svg.selectAll(".jA_shadow_large")
           .transition()
           .delay(1960)
           .duration(1)
           .attr("r", 80);
    }, 2000);
})();
```

```css
circle {
   fill: #8BC34A;
   stroke: white;
   stroke-width: 2px;
}

text {
    fill: white;
}

/*****************/
/* CSS KeyFrames */
/*****************/
#svg_keyframes{
  animation:filters 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes filters {
  0%{ 
    -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px #333); 
  }
  100% { 
    -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 30px #333); 
  }
}

/***********************************/
/* CSS KeyFrames using SVG Filters */
/***********************************/

.kf_Shadow1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: shadow-expand; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: shadow-expand;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.kf_Fill1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: circle-fill; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: circle-fill;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.kf_DropShadow1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: drop-shadow-expand; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: drop-shadow-expand;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* Demonstrate that fill works correctly */
@keyframes circle-fill {
    0% { fill: #FF0000; }       
    25% { fill: #BB0033; }       
    50% { fill: #990066; }        
    75% { fill: #4400aa; }         
    100% { fill: #0000ff; }       
}

/* Demonstrate that filter doesn't work as hoped */
@keyframes shadow-expand {
    0% { filter: url(#f1); -webkit-filter: url(#f1);}       
    25% { filter: url(#f2); -webkit-filter: url(#f1);}       
    50% { filter: url(#f3); -webkit-filter: url(#f1);}       
    75% { filter: url(#f4); -webkit-filter: url(#f1);}       
    100% { filter: url(#f5); -webkit-filter: url(#f1);}       
}

@keyframes drop-shadow-expand {
    0% { -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 10px #333); }       
    25% { -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 15px #333); }       
    50% { -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 20px #333); }       
    75% { -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 25px #333); }       
    100% { -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 16px 30px #333); }       
}

/*************************/
/* SVG Filter Animations */
/*************************/

.fA_shadow {
  filter: url(#f1);
}

/*************************/
/* JavaScript Animations */
/*************************/
.jA_shadow {
    filter: url(#f1);
    stroke: none !important;
}

.jA_shadow_expanding {
    filter: url(#f1);
    stroke: none !important;
    fill: #CCC !important;
}

.jA_shadow_large {
    filter: url(#f2);
     stroke: none !important;
    fill: #CCC !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1>CSS Keyframes</h1>
<p>The downside here is that the animation seems to require attaching to the svg element, which causes all of the circles to animate their drop shadows</p>
<svg id="svg_keyframes" width="1000" height="280">
    <g transform="translate(120, 140)">
        <circle r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 1</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(420, 140)">
        <circle r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 2</text>
    </g>
</svg>


<h1>CSS Keyframes referencing SVG Filters</h1>
<p>Unfortunately it seems that this approach simply doesn't work. The idea was that the class would change triggering a keyframe which would progressively change the filter being applied by specifying gradually expanding filters</p>
<svg id="svg_filterKeyFrames" width="1000" height="280">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="10" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
        <filter id="f2" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="7" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="15" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
         <filter id="f3" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="10" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="20" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
         <filter id="f4" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="13" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="25" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
         <filter id="f5" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="16" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="30" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
     <g transform="translate(120, 140)">
        <circle class="kf_Shadow1" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-4.5em">Shadow should change</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(420, 140)">
        <circle class="kf_Fill1" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-4.5em">Colour should change</text>
    </g>
     <g transform="translate(720, 140)">
        <circle class="kf_DropShadow1" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-5.5em">Drop Shadow should change</text>
    </g>
</svg>

<h1>SVG Filters Animations</h1>
<p>SVG filter animations are another way to tackle this problem, but it seems that they behave very similar to a CSS filter in that because they are shared all of the elements update</p>
<svg id="svg_filterAnimation" width="1000" height="280">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
            <feGaussianBlur id="blur1" result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="10" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
     <g transform="translate(120, 140)">
        <circle class="fA_shadow" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 1</text>
    </g>
     <g transform="translate(420, 140)">
        <circle class="fA_shadow" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 2</text>
    </g>
    <animate xlink:href="#blur1" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="10" to="30" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>

<h1>JavaScript Animations</h1>
<p>Animation via JavaScript is another approach, this uses D3 but the issue here is changing the size of gaussian blur that operates on the shadow is incredibly difficult as demonstrated in Circle 2</p>
<svg id="svg_javaScriptAnimation" width="1000" height="280">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
            <feGaussianBlur id="blur1" result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="10" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
         <filter id="f2" x="-40%" y="-40%" height="200%" width="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="4" />
            <feGaussianBlur id="blur1" result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="30" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
     <g transform="translate(120, 140)">
        <circle class="jA_shadow" r="110"/>
        <circle class="circle" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 1</text>
    </g>
     <g transform="translate(420, 140)">
        <circle class="jA_shadow_expanding" r="110"/>
        <circle class="circle" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 2</text>
    </g>
     <g transform="translate(720, 140)">
        <circle class="jA_shadow_large" r="80"/>
        <circle class="circle" r="110"/>
        <text dx="-1.5em">Circle 3</text>
    </g>
    <animate xlink:href="#blur1" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="10" to="30" dur="2s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS transition and CSS animation can only be used in cases where what you want to animate is controlled by CSS. Say, you can use it if you want to animate `stroke-width`. But it is very limited.

It is possible to use `<animate>` to animate SVG filters. Say, you can add an `id="blur1"` to `<feGaussianBlur>` of `f1` and use this to animate it: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyL24uaf/)

```
<animate xlink:href="#blur1" attributeName="stdDeviation"
from="10" to="30" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

The `begin` attribute can theoretically be bound to an event, say `mouseover`, but your mileage may vary because it is bound to the filter task, which is not useful at all.

A third alternative is to animate it using JavaScript `requestAnimationFrame`. You will need to write a lot of code, and it will not be GPU-accelerated, but you always get what you want.

Comment: Just looking at the JSFiddle and that's exactly the sort of thing I'm after... The animation actually needs to occur on a click or class change - but I'm guessing that doesn't make things any easier?

Comment: You can start SMIL on a click, just change the begin attribute.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just looking at trying to change this - the animate object doesn't seem to be 'bound' to an item per-se. So if I scale this up and have 100 circles in the SVG, do I then need 100 animate elements too?

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle to trigger SMIL on click. https://jsfiddle.net/kyL24uaf/1/

Comment: @AlanTam ok, that makes sense and I can do that. Is there a way to get the stop the animation? It seems to automatically reset to the blur of 10 at the end of the animation?

Comment: @Ian If your 100 circles animate together, you only need one `<animate>`. Otherwise you need 100. Fair?

Comment: @Ian To make it stay, add `fill="freeze"` to `<animate>`. https://jsfiddle.net/kyL24uaf/2/

Comment: @Ian You can end it programmatically via `endElement`.

Comment: @RobertLongson We cannot use `begin="click"` in this case because the animation is attached to the `feGaussianBlur` element, not the circle.

Comment: @AlanTam - ok, I think I'm following. I've got a new fiddle with 3 circles https://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/kyL24uaf/4/ if I click one, I want just that one to animate. I can't figure out how the animate gets shared across the all instances... if I click one, shouldn't that trigger `animate1` just using that element as the `SourceGraphic`? Or is it because they're all sharing the same filter? Also is there a way to animate multiple properties at once?

Comment: They all share the same filter so they all update. You can have multiple animate elements, each animating a different property.

Comment: @AlanTam You **can** use begin. begin="elementid.click" is what you want where elementid is the id of the element you're clicking on.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've put together an example of what I've got so far - nothing is quite working how I'd like it yet http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/pjwqp75y/ . Ultimately I need resizing of a circle + increase the size of the box-shadow/deviation of the blur, able to operate individually on elements when there may be several hundred.

Comment: @Ian You're going to need several hundred filters.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Yeah, which I really don't want to do. I'm even open to doing it in JS - but I'm struggling to get that working with my `D3` example at the bottom

Comment: @RobertLongson I've managed to find a way using only 20 filters for as many circles as required - using JavaScript. Checkout circle 4 at the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/pjwqp75y/ it uses D3 and tweens the filter attribute over the period of the animation to one of 20 different filters