# How to gradually change attribute values with Javascript? eg. Ease-in, Ease-out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change an element's attribute (a filter for an SVG) from 0 to 10 and back to 0 infinitely. For this I made a js function breathe:

```
let flag = 0;
let loader = setInterval(breathe, 1000);

function breathe() {
  if (flag === 0) {
    document
      .getElementById("main-blur")
      .setAttribute("stdDeviation", "10");
    flag = 1;
    return;
  } else {
    document
      .getElementById("main-blur")
      .setAttribute("stdDeviation", "0");
    flag = 0;
    return;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the blur value changes from 10 to 0 directly. I want it to gradually increase and decrease for a breathing type effect.

Comment: [Transition an SVG Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135739/transition-an-svg-filter)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for the JS solution rather than using [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate), you should use [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
// Get a reference to the SVG filter only once:
const gaussianBlur =  document.getElementById('gaussianBlur');

// To control the animation: 0 to 100 we increase blur, 100 to 200 we decrease blur. We use these
// values instead of 0-10 and then divide by 10 to produce a smoother animation.
let step = 0;

function tick() {
  const blur = step < 100 ? step : 200 - step;

  // Update blur (converting step to 0-10). You could change this to take into account time:
  gaussianBlur.setAttribute('stdDeviation', blur / 10);

  // Update step:
  step = (step + 1) % 200;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

tick();
```

```css
#element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg id="element" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blurFilter" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
    <feGaussianBlur id="gaussianBlur" />
  </filter>
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="filter: url(#blurFilter); " />
</svg>
```

Otherwise, using `<animate>`, you need  to use its [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/values) and [`keyTimes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keyTimes) attributes:

```css
#element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg id="element" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blurFilter" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
    <feGaussianBlur id="gaussianBlur" stdDeviation="1" />
  </filter>
  
  <animate
    xlink:href="#gaussianBlur"
    attributeName="stdDeviation"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    values="0; 10; 0"
    keyTimes="0; .5; 1"
  />
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="filter: url(#blurFilter); " />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a simple number incrementor/decrementor like so:

```js
let delta = 1;
let current = 0;
let loader = setInterval(breathe, 1000);
function breathe() {

    if (current === 10) delta = -1;
    else if (current === 0) delta = 1;
    current += delta;
    document.getElementById("main-blur")
        .setAttribute("stdDeviation", String(current));


}
```